# Inconsistent element rendering and spacing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-rendering

I recently started creating a simple concept for a Javascript game based around tiles, but when I was positioning the tiles, I found a problem with the display.
http://i.gyazo.com/8328507c64b4254a6271172892ca3f92.png

In the picture, a couple of columns are dragged up around 0.5px and 1px, and this is highly undesirable.

I have tested this in Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer and they all have trouble aligning the tiles: Chrome has trouble vertically, Firefox and IE horizontally.

The CSS code for both the container and the tiles (There are 200 in the container) is the following:

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.tile {
    width:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-4px;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    position:relative;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

EDIT: The HTML code, by request:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="tile tile_0_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_1_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_2_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_3_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_4_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_5_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_6_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_7_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_8_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_9_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_10_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_11_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_12_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_13_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_14_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_15_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_16_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_17_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_18_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_19_0"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_0_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_1_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_2_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_3_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_4_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_5_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_6_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_7_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_8_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_9_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_10_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_11_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_12_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_13_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_14_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_15_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_16_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_17_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_18_1"></div>
    <div class="tile tile_19_1"></div>
    <!--Continues all the way to tile_19_9-->
</div>
```

Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the HTML too?

Comment: Also please show the javascript.  that could also be doing something here.

Comment: Added the HTML.
Also, javascript is doing nothing but setting the background-image to "url(graphics/tiles/wood.png)"

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without a live version of the code to play with, but one thing you might try is adding `font-size: 0;` to the `#container`.

The reason I bring that up is that your `.tile`s are `inline-block`, which means the browser is going to collapse the newlines between them in your HTML source into text spaces. (See [this article about space between `inline-block` elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more information.)

At that point, you may be able to remove the negative `margin-right` and `margin-bottom` from your `.tile`s as well.